# mapping list items onto tensorflow dataset dictionary

Tags: python, tensorflow, dictionary, mapping, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to map image information to a dataset consisting of a dictionary of images and labels.

`parse_function()` should just decode from 2 lists of file name paths and labels.

```
 def parse_function(filename, label):
    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
    image_resized = tf.image.resize(image_decoded, [4, 4])

    return image_resized, label

def dataset_maker(list_sample_paths, list_labels):

    filenames = tf.constant(list_sample_paths)
    labels = tf.constant(list_labels)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({"image": filenames, "label": labels})
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)

training_dataset = dataset_maker(list_training_sample_paths, list_training_sample_labels)
```

But I'm getting this error message

```
TypeError: tf__parse_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'
```

Do I need to use dict comprehension in this case?
Any help in solving this is very much appreciated.
Thanks!

*Adding this info after Srihari Humbarwadi's response to solve it with tuples:*
Id like to get a dictionary structure because I rained my model with Mnist.

One random Mnist example has this structure:

```
{'image': <tf.Tensor: id=140275, shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=uint8, numpy=array([[[  0],[  0],[  0]],dtype=uint8)>, 'label': <tf.Tensor: id=140276, shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=6>}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass the list of filenames and labels in the form of a dictionary. You can get it to work by passing a tuple ie. `(filenames, labels)`. Here is the complete code that I used:

```
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

print('TensorFlow:', tf.__version__)

list_training_sample_paths = sorted(glob('images/*'))
# random integer labels
list_training_sample_labels = np.random.randint(low=0, high=5, size=[len(list_training_sample_paths)])

def parse_function(filename, label):
    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
    image_resized = tf.image.resize(image_decoded, [4, 4])

    return image_resized, label

def dataset_maker(list_sample_paths, list_labels):

    filenames = tf.constant(list_sample_paths)
    labels = tf.constant(list_labels)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)
    return dataset

training_dataset = dataset_maker(list_training_sample_paths, list_training_sample_labels)
tf.data.experimental.get_structure(training_dataset)
```

**Output**

```
TensorFlow: 2.2.0-rc2
(TensorSpec(shape=(4, 4, None), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(),dtype=tf.int64, name=None))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That would work but I'm trying to get it into a dictionary structure because he model I used before was built to work with the Mnist dataset.

Mnist has a dictionary-like structure with "image" and "label" keys like here: (picking a random sample from mnist)

{'image': <tf.Tensor: id=140275, shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=uint8, numpy=array([[[  0],[  0],[  0]],dtype=uint8)>, 'label': <tf.Tensor: id=140276, shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=6>}

any thoughts on how to get there?

Answer (score 0):

The arguments passed to your mapping function should match to your dataset object's element types. So, if your elements are a `dict`, you can pass a `dict` in your `parse_function` and return a `dict`.
For example:

```
def parse_function(data):

    data_out = data
    filename = data['image']
    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
    image_resized = tf.image.resize(image_decoded, [4, 4])
    data_out['image'] = image_resized

    return data_out

def dataset_maker(list_sample_paths, list_labels):

    filenames = tf.constant(list_sample_paths)
    labels = tf.constant(list_labels)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({"image": filenames, "label": labels})
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)
    return dataset

training_dataset = dataset_maker(list_training_sample_paths, list_training_sample_labels)
```

Alternatively, you can pass a tuple like @Srihari Humbarwadi suggested and return a dict. Like this:

```
def parse_function(filename, label):

    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
    image_resized = tf.image.resize(image_decoded, [4, 4])
    data_out = {'image': image_resized, 'label': label}

    return data_out

def dataset_maker(list_sample_paths, list_labels):

    filenames = tf.constant(list_sample_paths)
    labels = tf.constant(list_labels)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)
    return dataset
```

Comment: thanks again for the help before. there's one more question about the tensor information. I'm not sure how Mnist includes an "id" value like here in both image and label keys like in this Mnist sample here: <tf.Tensor: id=140275, shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=uint8, numpy=array([[[  0],[  0],[  0]]], dtype=uint8)>. Do you know how to add an ID info?